# Unable to put bounty on my question

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, bounties

Recently, I posted an iOS related question that have been nagging me for some time : [Localizing the Cut|Copy|Paste menu on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11224969/598857)

In the spirit of the stacks, I would like to put a bounty on it, to get the right answer faster, or at least get some clues to where to look.

Only one person have answered, and that was dead wrong.

But I don't see the bounty link anywhere ? or the "Bounty in two days..." link either?

How come I can't put a bounty here ? I have been able to do so on several of my other stacks with great success.

[image]
(and yes, im fully logged in here.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Wait for only 2 days.

Comment: This appears nowhere on the page, that's why I have retagged this as a bug.

Comment: Do you see that on other new questions in other sites? Do you see this link here on this question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you did manage to put a bounty on the question in the meantime, the functionality itself obviously works. So what's left is the question why you didn't see the "question eligible for bounty in X".

We made a change quite a while ago to show this info (with a link to the corresponding FAQ section) *only if the question has no answers*, because usually that's when you're bounty-trigger-happy – when you don't have answers.

In hindsight however, it seems this causes more confusion than its decluttering of the interface is helping, so from the next build on, we'll only hide it if the question has an *accepted* answer.

Comment: Cheers, it just wasn't documented anywhere. (Was it? :))

Comment: FWIW after reading this question I want to go find an example of the "bounty can be offered in X days" text and couldn't find ot; guess this was why

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't think so, I wasn't even aware of this until I checked the code :)

Comment: Hidden code? Sound like waffles! ;) @Ben you can see this only on your own questions.

Answer (score 5):

From [the bounty page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) linked from the FAQ:

> **Which questions are eligible?**
>
> If you don't see the bounty button on a question, one or more of the
>   following applies:
>
> - The question has been asked in the last 48 hours. Give the community a
>     chance to answer your question normally first. You already have three
>     outstanding bounties.
> - You can only have three open bounties at any one
>     time. To start a bounty on this question, you must award at least one
>     of the previous bounties first.
> - The question already has a bounty. To
>     start a second bounty on this question, you must wait for the current
>     bounty to be awarded first.

The question was asked only 22 hours ago.  So you need to wait a little longer :)

Comment: But I don't see the bounty link anywhere ? or the "Bounty in two days..." link either ? ( OP Said in question )

Comment: @Lucifer: I didn't know there was supposed to be a placeholder link prior to bounty eligibility.  Maybe it's changed and the FAQ needs to catch up?

Comment: @David yes there surely is, see my answer. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Ah, now I remember seeing that in the past.  Strange.

Comment: I am aware that it takes some time to be elegable for a bounty, but usually I get informed of this. Notice what I see in the question (just added screenshot.)

Answer (score 1):

You **should** see such thing:

> > [image]

(Only a mockup based on my own question, only author of the question can see this link)

If you don't see that message then it's a bug.

Comment: As shown in my OP, I don't have that link/message anywhere...

Comment: So that's a bug - retag your question. :)

Comment: I will retag it then :]

Comment: [Mellemrum](http://translate.google.com/#auto|en|Mellemrum) versus [mellemrum](http://translate.google.com/#auto|en|mellemrum), funny people ;-)

Comment: @Arjan sorry I lost you - commented on the wrong post maybe? (but yeah, funny that case matters! :))